# Delete all from excel sheet and leave top row (column headers) ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

still a rookie in SSIS

I Need to delete all data from an excel sheet but leave the column headers, to refresh the data
by adding new data / update data from a SQL table

how do I do this in SSIS

I have tried the SQL task of drop table [ExcelDataSheet$] but I loose the top row obviously

I have tried  drop table [ExcelDataSheet$A10000:B10000] it does not work

or plan b

is there a command you can say refresh the SQL on a sheet? via SSIS

please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to delete rows in an excel sheet using SSIS.  What you can do is to keep an empty version of your excel somewhere (like a template).  And then in SSIS you can use a file task to copy this template and overwrite the excel sheet with the data.

Comment: I have to update a excel sheet from an external source , that the data changes on the other sheets so the template method wont work x